# How to import file in the swSrc while using Wrokbox

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, workbox

How can I import file in the swSrc while using Wrokbox.
I want to import file in sw.js

```
InjectManifest({
        swSrc: "./src/sw.js",
        swDest: "service-worker.js"
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importScripts` global function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries.

You can not use ES2015 `import` though. It is not natively supported.

Comment: i have to import the idb and Storage file. I have code as below. ```importScripts("https://unpkg.com/idb@5.0.0/build/cjs/index.js", "/Storage.js", "/precache-manifest.338ef4bfe6ec3c2b842ee6c3c962f4f8.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.3/workbox-sw.js");
```  But It throws an error while importing idb from following url. But  it work fine for Storage.js file Any Idea

Comment: While using import in the Storage.js  It throws  Cannot use import statement outside a module. I am using the webpack in react for this project. so, chaning the build fie in every build is also pain.